# Dozer Mapping behavior changes when i use map-id. Nested Arrays aren't being mapped! What i'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, json, dozer, mapper

I'm currently using Dozer to do all mappings.
I'm trying to solve a new requirement and i thought of using map-id to solve it.

- When endpoint /products is called only root fields must be presented.
- When endpoint /products/{id} is called all fields must be presented, nested included.

**I realize that i have bad results with map-id.**

**So i ask:**

- can i use map-id to resolve my issues? how ?
- Is there another solution? how?

**/products**

*With map-id the list of products does not show price:*

```
[
{
   "id": "a5f206e4",
   "name": "bike",
   "type": "MOUNTAIN",
   "description": "ddsfsdf",
   "price": null
},
...
]
```

*Without map-id the list of products show price:*

```
[
{
   "id": "a5f206e4",
   "name": "bike",
   "type": "MOUNTAIN",
   "description": "ddsfsdf",
   "price": {
        "unit": "€",
        "value": 100
   }
},
...
]
```

**/products/{id}**

*When i call GET /products/{id}, i do*

```
 ProductDto productDto = Converter.DOZER.getMapper().map(product, ProductDto.class);
```

**Product Detail (When no map-id is defined)**

```
{
"product": {
   "id": "a5f206e4",
   "name": "bike",
   "type": "MOUNTAIN",
   "description": "ddsfsdf",
   "price": {
        "unit": "€",
        "value": 100
   }, 
   "product_groups": [
    {
        "id": "066dd1a0-",
        "name": "jjjjjjjjj",
        "type": "OWNON",
        "description": "Own",          
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "a5f206e4",
                "name": "bike",
                "type": "MOUNTAIN",
                "description": "ddsfsdf",
                "price": {
                    "unit": "€",
                    "value": 100
                },              
                 "product_groups": [
                    {
                        "id": "066dd1a0-",
                        "name": "jjjjjjjjj",
                        "type": "OWNON",
                        "description": "Own"
                    }
                ],                  
                "products": []                  
            }
        ]
    }],
    "products": [
        ....
    ]
}
}
```

**Product Detail (When map-id is defined)**

```
ProductDto productDto = Converter.DOZER.getMapper().map(product, ProductDto.class, "detail");


{
"product": {
   "id": "a5f206e4",
   "name": "bike",
   "type": "MOUNTAIN",
   "description": "ddsfsdf",
   "price": {
        "unit": "€",
        "value": 100
   }, 
   "product_groups": [
    {
        "id": "066dd1a0-",
        "name": "jjjjjjjjj",
        "type": "OWNON",
        "description": "Own",          
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "a5f206e4",
                "name": "bike",
                "type": "MOUNTAIN",
                "description": "ddsfsdf",
                "price": null,  (is not null)           
                "product_groups": null,  (is not null)              
                "products": null (is not null)
            }
        ]
    }],
    "products": [
        ....
    ]
}
}
```

mappings.xml

```
   <mapping type="one-way" map-null="true">
       <class-a>com.xxx.ProductGroup</class-a>
       <class-b>com.xxx.ProductGroupDto</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>products</a>
            <b>productList</b>
        </field>
   </mapping>      
   <mapping type="one-way" map-null="true" map-id="detail">
       <class-a>com.xxx.Product</class-a>
       <class-b>com.xxx.ProductDto</class-b>

        <field>
            <a>priceValue</a>
            <b>price.value</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>priceUnit</a>
            <b>price.unit</b>
        </field>                        
        <field>
            <a>products</a>
            <b>productList</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>productGroups</a>
            <b>productGroupList</b>
        </field>
   </mapping>   
   <!-- EVEN WITH THESE MAPPINGS, LIST OF PRODUCTS DOES NOT SHOW PRICE -->
   <mapping type="one-way" map-null="true" >
       <class-a>com.xxx.Product</class-a>
       <class-b>com.xxx.ProductDto</class-b>

        <field>
            <a>priceValue</a>
            <b>price.value</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>priceUnit</a>
            <b>price.unit</b>
        </field>    
  </mapping>
```